# how to effectively allocate memory for 20000*20000 matrix?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

My code follows the PCA algorithm in order to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a 20000 *35 matrix. So in order to find the eigenvector, I need to find the covariance matrix, which on calculation will be of an order of 20000*20000.

How will I process such a huge matrix? I am using OpenCV for my code

Comment: 1.6 GB can be byte addressed with a 32-bit number - why should he need a 64-bit system?

Comment: Is your matrix dense or sparse. If it is dense, your problem is probably intractable.

Comment: If you have the data on file, you can memory map it. However, since it's so large it's probably not feasible on a 32-bit system.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `20K * 20K * 8bytes = 3200 MB` But if it's a float matrix, you're right (except that you should have written 4 bytes then ;))

Comment: What would be considered an eigenvector of a non-square matrix?

Comment: My mistake. A double matrix of 20K*20K takes indeed 3.2GBytes. So a 64 bits system and processor is mandatory (unless you use dirty tricks).

Comment: This question doesn't make any mathematical sense. A non-square matrix, by definition, don't have eigenvalues. It has *singular values*, but not eigenvalues.

Comment: @pmg Extracting eigenvectors is O(N^3) IIRC so storing working state disk is no good.

Comment: Perhaps consider using a GPGPU with OpenCL....

Comment: @Carl: Because what 32-bit system has 1.6GB of *contiguous* free address space?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your question is probably ill formed; if you are doing PCA, your 20000 * 35 matrix most likely has 20000 observations on 35 variables (having 35 observations of 20000 variables would not be of much use, so i'm guessing it's not your case).

If such is the case, the covariance matrix has size 35 x 35, not 20k x 20k.

You can compute all eigenpairs for a 35x35 matrix using QR algorithm, Jacobi Method or any other eigenvalue/eigenvector approximating algorithm (many are specific for real symmetric matrices, as is the case of a covariance matrix).

Answer (score 2):

20K * 20K = 400,000,000. If you're using 32-bit floats, this is 1.6 GB. It will be a beast of a matrix, but most modern computers should be able to handle that reasonably (reasonably here means that it won't take a week to process) without special optimization. If you're using 64-bit doubles, then you're looking at 3.2 GB, which is getting intense, but still not entirely unmanageable on a modern computer.

If you need this code to really perform well, then consider whether or not your matrix will be dense/sparse. If it's dense, there's not much you can do. If it's sparse, there are probably some optimizations you can make.

EDIT: Also, consider using OpenCL/CUDA for optimization. Generally speaking, problems involving matrices usually have high data-level parallelism and are amenable to GPU approaches.

Comment: First sentence is missing a few trailing zeros.